# AWS ec2 instance cost for per api call to third-party platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, http, amazon-ec2

I am unable to understand the costing and have gathered some information on how AWS ec2 instance cost. I know that the inbound data-transfer to ec2 is free. But can't catch up with outbound for specially third-party or public api calls. I am running a web-app server for rest apis on ec2. How do i calculate how does AWS can cost me for calling a post http api from my webapp. Do query strings params and headers along with it makes it a a hundred of bytes or upto a few KB that goes out while make request that's how i charged? or the response that i receive from that public rest api?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any traffic that goes from your EC2 instance to the Internet is counted as **Outbound Data Transfer**.

AWS doesn't care whether the data is headers, params, pictures, etc. It just counts the bytes that go to the Internet and charges accordingly. So, if lots of people download data from your instance, or if the instance sends data to a third-party site on the Internet, it all falls under this charge.

All the calculations are grouped together, so if you want to calculate the cost per API call, your application would need to keep track of how many bytes it sent to each destination and calculate the charges itself.

Incoming bytes from the Internet are *not* charged.